# Wdio - Get length of items list

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, webdriver-io

I have problem with correctly print length of items (li) from ul.
First of all, I save a selectors with li items. Next i invoke length method.
But when i run my test i get undefined as length of li.

My code:

```
get numberOfBooks() {
        return $$("fieldset > div.suggest-list > ol.item-list > li")
    }
```

```
 async TitleBookIsVisible() {
        await expect(this.numberOfBooks).toBeVisible();
        console.log(this.numberOfBooks.length)
    }
```

Return: undefined

//selector is correct

Comment: can you provide a link to the page you are working on?

Comment: Yes. https://helion.pl/ . I try get length of li on search popup after typed part of value.

Comment: first of all I see no elements matching `fieldset > div.suggest-list > ol.item-list > li`

Comment: List items appear only after entering the phrase in the search engine https://imgur.com/a/Eza4pM8

Comment: Did you try my locators? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use your locator, however it looks better with the following `xpath` `//li[@class='slick-slide slick-active']` or if you need `css` try this `li.slick-slide.slick-active`

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you use webdriverio async.
If that is the case, then you should first await for the list and then query the length of it. (await this.numberOfBooks).length;

Or you can extract it into a variable and check that afterwards.

```
const list = await this.numberOfBooks;
console.log(list.length); //should be defined here
```